# How to return two table in PostgreSQL

Tags: asp.net, postgresql

I'm new in POSTGRESQL and I am creating PostgreSQL functions, and now I want to create a function which returns two table output, I created and it does not work

my function

```
CREATE FUNCTION getData() RETURNS setof refcursor AS
$$
DECLARE c_top_items refcursor;
DECLARE c_shopping_cart refcursor;
BEGIN
    OPEN c_top_items FOR
        SELECT t.name
        FROM employee t
        LIMIT 10;
    RETURN NEXT c_top_items;
    OPEN c_shopping_cart FOR
        SELECT c.name
        FROM employee c
        LIMIT 5;
    RETURN NEXT c_shopping_cart;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Please help!!

Comment: Don't tag an RDBMS is if it isn't relevant to your question please. I have removed the conflicting tag for you.

Comment: On the first look function looks OK. How do you use it? Here is some relevant article about it - http://www.sqlines.com/postgresql/how-to/return_result_set_from_stored_procedure

Comment: The example does not try to return "tow tables", just the `name` column of selected rows. What exactly are you trying to achieve. Please [edit] the question and *always* provide your version of Postgres.

Answer (score 0):

When you call getData you get two cursors, fetch all from them. I modified the example in the documentation and fetched the data with:

```
select * from getData();

fetch all in "<unnamed portal 1>";
fetch all in "<unnamed portal 2>";
```

But you would probably be better off by changing the signature of the function according to the *return multiple cursors*-example in the documentation. This is that example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION myfunc(refcursor, refcursor) RETURNS SETOF refcursor AS $$
BEGIN
    OPEN $1 FOR SELECT * FROM table_1;
    RETURN NEXT $1;
    OPEN $2 FOR SELECT * FROM table_2;
    RETURN NEXT $2;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

-- need to be in a transaction to use cursors.
BEGIN;

SELECT * FROM myfunc('a', 'b');

FETCH ALL FROM a;
FETCH ALL FROM b;
COMMIT;
```

See: [Returning Cursors](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/plpgsql-cursors.html#AEN57590)